# Convert Map with Set of Strings as key to Map with Strings (Java)

Tags: java, dictionary, java-8, stream, java-11

the question is not difficult, and I have already solved it in my own way, but I would like to hear your opinion, maybe there is some way to make this an improved option? Java 8-11.

```
Map<Set<String>, User> --> Map<String, User>
```

Imagine, that elements inside of the set are won't repeat. One more note: many unique keys can point to the same value.

I made this with the following code:

```
Map<String, User> result = new HashMap<>();
existingMap.forEach((set, user) -> set.forEach(item -> result.put(set, user)));
```

So, my question is - is there a better way to do it? I mean, maybe Stream API already has some methods to do it? in the scope of 'collect' method

Comment: I have a hard time wrapping my head around the premises. In Map<Set<String>, User>, many unique keys can point to the same value ?

Comment: @ChrisNeve yes, many unique keys will point to the same value (also updated question)

Comment: Sounds like a dangerous place to be. That's not what maps are meant for. Would probably make more sense to have Map<User, Set<String>>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a collector, you can do a `flatMap` first, then `toMap`:

```
Map<String, User> result = existingMap.entrySet().stream().flatMap(
        entry -> entry.getKey().stream()
            .map(s -> Map.entry(s, entry.getValue()))
    )
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue));
```

Or if you just want to use `collect` only (this is more similar to your original approach):

```
Map<String, User> result = existingMap.entrySet().stream().collect(
    HashMap::new,
    (map, entry) -> entry.getKey().forEach(x -> map.put(x, entry.getValue())),
    HashMap::putAll
);
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem cannot be solved.

Consider the following:

1. `("Bill", "Tom", "Alice") -> User1`
2. `("Bill", "Tom", "Jane") -> User2`

This is valid for structure 1 (`Map<Set<String>, User>`) but invalid for structure 2 (`Map<String, User>`) as it will cause data loss (information about Bill and Tom will be lost).

An alternate structure you may consider is the conversion from `Map<Set<String>, User>` to `Map<String, Set<User>>`, which will not result in data degradation.

Edit: to assume data loss is acceptable as per the comments, a normal for loop solution would be:

```
Map<String, User> results = new HashMap<>();
for (Set<String> key : existing.keySet())
{
    User v = existing.get(key);
    for (String k : key)
    {
        results.put(k, v);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think "Imagine, that elements inside of the set are won't repeat" rules this out?

Comment: @John 
Yes, I totally understand that data can be lost, but in my case - elements inside of the Set are won't repeat

Comment: @Sweeper I took that to mean the regular set restriction of no duplicates inside a set.  If values within the set are globally unique across all of the sets, then yes, the problem can be solved.  The code OP posted is sufficient and any other is a matter of opinion (I generally dislike lambdas and streams and would do it as a normal for loop, but I know younger people seem to love lambdas and streams).